# Why is XPath returning value of '0' using Ruby, Nokogiri and Watir?

Tags: ruby, xpath, web-crawler, nokogiri, bots

I'm working on a white-hat web-crawler that will periodically log into my account and check some information for me using Ruby with Watir and Nokogiri.

Here's the simplified HTML I'm trying to pull information from:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-lg hidden-md" style="z-index: 1002">
    <div class="banner-g">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="user-info">
                    <div id="acct-value">
                        <a href="https://www.testsite.org/Profile/MyShares" title="Change in value of your shares">GAIN/LOSS <span class="SPShares">-$12.85</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="committed">
                        <a href="https://www.testsite.org/Profile/MyShares" title="Amount paid for your shares">INVESTED <span class="SPPortfolio">$152.11</span></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="avail">
                        <a href="https://www.testsite.org/Profile/MyShares">AVAILABLE <span class="SPBalance">$26.98</span></a>
                    </div>
```

I'm trying to pull the `$26.98.` at the bottom of the excerpt.

Here are three snippets of code I'm using. They're all pretty much identical except for the XPath. The first two return their values perfectly, but the third always returns a value of "0" even though it 'should' return "$26.98" or "26.98".

```
 val_one = page_html.xpath(".//*[@id='openone']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").text.gsub(/\D/,'').to_i

 val_two = page_html.xpath(".//*[@id='opentwo']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]").text.gsub(/\D/,'').to_i

 val_three = page_html.xpath(".//*[@id='avail']/a/span").text.gsub(/\D/,'').to_i
 puts val_three
```

I assume it's a problem with the XPath, but I've gone through dozens of XPath troubleshooting questions here and none have worked. I checked the XPath with both FirePath and "XPath Checker". I also tried having the XPath search for the "SPBalance" class but that gave the same result.

When I remove `to.i` from the end, it returns a blank line instead of a zero.

Elsewhere in the site when using Watir, I was able to fix problems recording a value by calling `.focus`, but for this piece of the code, which is more Nokogiri, using `.focus` causes the error message:

```
undefined method `focus' for []:Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet (NoMethodError)
```

I assume `.focus` doesn't work for Nokogiri.

Update: Replaced HTML with a cleaner/more complete version.

I've continued to play around with different ways of reaching that data cell, including xpath, css and a search method. Someone told me xpath wouldn't work for this page so I spent even more time trying to get css to work. Someone else told me the page had Javascript, which would prevent Watir from working. So I tried rewriting the app for Selenium instead. Selenium did not solve the problem, and created a whole host of other problems.

Update: After following advice from the Tin Man, I've found that the node is not actually visible in the HTML when it is downloaded using curl.

I'm now trying to access the node using Watir instead of Nokogiri (as he suggested). 
Here's some of what I've tried so far:

```
avail_funds = browser.span :class => 'SPBalance'
avail_funds.exists?
avail_funds.text

avail_funds = browser.span(:css, 'span[customattribute]').text
avail_funds = browser.div(:id => "avail").a(:href => "/Profile/MyShares").span(:class => "SPBalance").text
avail_funds = browser.span(:xpath, ".//*[@id='avail']/a/span").text
avail_funds = browser.span(:css, 'span[class="SPBalance"]').text
avail_funds = browser.span.text
avail_funds = browser.div.text

browser.span(:class, "SPBalance").focus
avail_funds = browser.span(:class, "SPBalance").text 

avail_funds = @browser.span(:class => 'SPBalance').inner_html
puts @browser.spans(:class => "SPBalance")
puts @browser.span(:class => "SPBalance")

texts = @browser.spans(:class => "SPBalance").map do |span|
  span.text
end
```

So far all of the above return either blank lines or an error message.

The div class with the ID "user-info" is visible within the HTML as downloaded via curl. Everything beneath that, however, is not visible.

When I try:

```
avail_funds = browser.div(:id => "user-info").text
```

I get only blank lines.

When I try:

```
avail_funds = browser.div(:class => "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-xs hidden-sm").text
```

I get actual text back! But unfortunately the string does not contain the value I want.

I also tried:

```
puts browser.html
```

Because I thought if the value where visible in that version of the HTML, as it is through my Firefox plug-in, I could parse down to the value I want. But unfortunately the value is not visible in that version of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

By first 2 commands you fetch data directly from table cell beginning from the root of the document, and in the last one you starting from the center.

Try out to give span id and get data again, and then grow up the complexity and you will find your error in xpath

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Still no luck, but I updated my original question based on your comments. Did I understand your recommendations correctly?

Comment: The main recommendation is simple, as always- make it work, and THEN refactor. So, when it works, you may cut xpath and test what will be in console or with tests.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I won't even think about refactoring until I get it to work. I'd use an xpath three lines long if it'd give me the correct value.

Comment: A long selector is less likely to find what you want than a shorter one. Long selectors try to take too much of the document into account and minor changes to the document can break the code. Instead, use small selectors that find landmarks and navigate from them.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is you're trying to use a long, too-long, selector that is referencing tags that don't exist:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<head>
<body class="cbp-spmenu-push">
<div id="FreshWidget" class="freshwidget-container responsive" data-html2canvas-ignore="true" style="display: none;">
<div id="freshwidget-button" class="freshwidget-button fd-btn-right" data-html2canvas-ignore="true" style="display: none; top: 235px;">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/css/NavPushComponent.css"/>
<script src="/Scripts/classie.js"/>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr.custom.js"/>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top hidden-lg hidden-md" style="z-index: 1002">
<div class="banner-g">
<div class="container">
<div id="user-info">
<div id="acct-value">
<div id="committed">
<div id="avail">
<a href="/Profile/MyBalance">
AVAILABLE 
<span class="SPBalance">$31.59</span>
EOT

doc.at('tbody') # => nil
```

> ```
> ".//*[@id='openone']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]"
> ".//*[@id='opentwo']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]"
> ```

There is no `<tbody>` tag in your sample, and there rarely is in HTML created in the wild, especially if people created it manually. We usually see `<tbody>` in HTML someone grabbed from a browser's "View Source" display, which is the resulting output after their engine has mangled the HTML in an attempt to make it readable. Don't use that output. Instead, *ALWAYS* go straight to the source and use `wget` or `curl` and download the page and inspect it with an editor, or even use `nokogiri some_url` on the command-line and look at it there.

A second problem is your HTML snippet is invalid because it's full of unterminated tags. Nokogiri will do fixups on bad HTML, which can actually move nodes around, making it difficult to find nodes, especially when debugging. In this particular case Nokogiri is able to terminate them, but it's important to honor tag closures.

Here's what I'd use:

```
value = doc.at('span.SPBalance').text # => "$31.59"
```

This is using CSS which is usually much more readable than XPath. `at` means "find the first occurrence" and is equivalent to `search('span.SPBalance').first`.

The XPath equivalent would be:

```
doc.at('//span[@class="SPBalance"]')
doc.at('//span[@class="SPBalance"]').text # => "$31.59"
```

Once I have the value then it's easy to manipulate it.

```
value[/[\d.]+/].to_f # => 31.59
```

Moving on...

> the third always returns a value of "0" even though it should return "$31.59" or "31.59"

```
'$31.58'.to_i # => 0
'$'.to_i # => 0
'31.58'.to_i # => 31
'$31.58'.to_f # => 0.0
'31.58'.to_f # => 31.58
```

The documentation for [`to_f`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-to_f) and [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) say respectively:

> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as a floating point number.

and

> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an integer base base (between 2 and 36).

In both cases "leading characters" is significant.

---

> using .focus causes the error message:
>
> ```
>    undefined method `focus' for []:Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet (NoMethodError)
> ```
>
> I assume .focus doesn't work for Nokogiri.

You could always check [the NodeSet documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet), which confirms that `focus` is not a method.

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful advice! Lots of good info there. For the past ten days I've been trying hard to implement it. I tried 'avail_funds = page_html.at('span.SPBalance').text' as per your suggestion. Unfortunately I'm getting the error message: `<main>': undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) I've used the .text method elsewhere in the program to scrape this same page, so I'm not sure why it's causing problems now. The xpath version returns the same error message. I've also tried using css, and writing the program for Selenium instead of Watir.

Comment: You get the "undefined method" after `at` because the selector didn't find a matching node. If you can find the node when viewing the source downloaded with `curl` or `wget` then you can get it via `at` and a selector. If you it's only visible in a browser then it's DHTML and added after the page has loaded and you'll have to use a WATIR-type tool.

Comment: Okay, I had saved the HTML of the page before, but not with curl or wget. I didn't understand that that would make a difference. But now, after downloading it using curl I see that you're absolutely right, the node is not visible. I'm working now on figuring out how to use Watir to check the value of the node. No luck so far. Even requesting just browser.span.text returns a blank line. No luck with CSS either, but I'll keep playing with it....

Comment: It's possible to parse the JavaScript used to modify a page without using a JavaScript interpreter, but you have to rely on slicing and dicing the data as a string. You extract the information necessary to get the next page/script and step through until you get the final page you want. That's the old-school way of doing it.

Comment: Okay, intellectually that makes sense, though I'm not certain how to do that in terms of mechanics and syntax (and am so far finding only a limited amount of into via Google). Would I need to use a JavaScript parser like Rkelly/Rkelly remix? And is that something that will be compatible with Watir?

Comment: Research research research. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421 All that information is out there. Look at what WATIR does. Does it supply anything that can do JavaScript interpretation?

Comment: Right, I wasn't about to post a new SO question or anything. Just responding to your comment. But regardless, I solved the problem today! Turned out not to be a JavaScript problem at all. I had the code to check the given node (which was itself fine) immediately after the sequence to log into the site (via a pop up window). As it turned out, the program was looking for the node while the site was still logging me in. So of course the node wasn't accessible, the page hadn't finished loading yet. Seems obvious in hind sight. Thanks for your help